# Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
getBrand: function(brandId) {
  for(var i=0; i<malls.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<malls[i].brands.length; j++){
      //console.log(malls[i][brands[j]);
      //console.log(malls[i].brands[j].id);
      if(malls.brands[j].id==(brandId)){
        console.log(malls.brands[j].id);
        return malls.brands[j].id;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need help please, and in my console i get this message:TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Shouldn't it be `malls[i].brands[j].id`?

Comment: @Vohuman post this as an answer ...

Comment: Ha, this happens to me all the time when I forget to specify an index after a `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName` or `querySelectorAll` method call…

Comment: i have this message Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an array of objects and each object has a `brands` property that contains an array of objects. Your second `for` loop assumes the `malls` array itself has `brands` property which is not true. As the `malls.brands` is `undefined` you get that error.

Change:

```
if (malls.brands[j].id==(brandId)) {
```

to:

```
if (malls[i].brands[j].id==(brandId)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Vohuman pointed, i think you should write `malls[i].brands[j]` in order to access the array `brands` inside your object `malls[i]`, otherwise you're accessing to the whole `malls` objects array which doesn't have a `brands` array property

```
getBrand: function(brandId) {
  for(var i=0; i<malls.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<malls[i].brands.length; j++){
      if(malls[i].brands[j].id==(brandId)){
        console.log(malls[i].brands[j].id);
        return malls[i].brands[j].id;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this and avoid the fuss.

```
for(var mall of malls) {
    for(var brand of mall) {
        if(brand.id == brandId) return brand.id;
    }
}
```